# AWS Athena Returning Zero Records from Tables Created from GLUE Crawler database using parquet from S3

Tags: amazon-s3, parquet, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have created parquet files from SQL data using python. I am able to read the data on my local machine, so I know the parquet files are valid. I created a Glue Crawler that creates a database from Parquet files in S3 and the database shows the correct amount of records in the glue dashboard.

When I query that database in Athena it shows "No Results", but does show the column names.

Please see the images below for reference.

[GLUE Table Properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRrZI.jpg)
[Athena Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tl1a.jpg)

Comment: Your table name on the catalog is pm**10801**_parquet and you are trying to query a pm**80100**_parquet. I really don't know how the hell it returned your empty table anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. You cannot point to the root of the S3 bucket with parquet files in that location. Each parquet file needs to be in a folder that has the same name as your file. I don't think this is required, but for automation purposes, it makes the most sense...

Comment: Crawlers can be tricky to setup, but this is not the case. You can have all files in a single folder (no folder too) or divide them by folders to partition.